# Append a value in Json field of a postgres table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I trying to append a JSON value in the Postgres table

**Table structure**

```
id | name | field
------------------------------------
1  | jack |{age:22, place:"london"}
2  | rocky|{age:34, place:"nyc"}
```

for the first records, I'm appending the value "NYC" to the existing value(example: {age:22, place:"London,NYC"}
and for the second record, I'm replacing the existing value "nyc" to "SFO"

```
update table
set field->>place = field->>place + "NYC"
where id =1

update table
set field->>place = "SFO"
where id =2
```

but the first record is not getting updated.

Comment: Are you really using postgresql 9.3 ? In any case `+` is not a json operator, see the list in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE). To append two values with the same json key, I would suggest you to create a json array : `UPDATE table SET field = json_set(field, '{place}', json_build_array(field->>place, 'nyc'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `||` operator and `jsonb_build_object`.

```sql
update the_table 
set field = field || jsonb_build_object('place', (field->>'place')||',NYC')
where id = 1;

update the_table 
set field = field || jsonb_build_object('place', 'SFO')
where id = 2;
```

NB: Postgres 9.5+
[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fGkCnQw1V3fqXP1aHmCX6q/1)

Comment: I'm getting an SQL error. `ERROR: operator does not exist: Json || Json`

Answer (score 1):

1. `+` operator never existed in PostreSQL for `json` or `jsonb` types. You might've had `||` in mind, for [string concatenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) which in some languages is a `+`.
2. When issuing an `update` you need to address a field. By using `->>` operator to the left of `=`, you're addressing a value extracted from the field instead, which breaks the syntax.
3. You forgot a comma before adding 'NYC' to 'London'.
4. [PostgreSQL versions before 10 are no longer supported, you're encouraged upgrade.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) On November 10, 2022, version 10 will no longer be supported either.

That being said, this [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/QfwdVIHf) on 9.3:

```sql
update test
set field = concat( '{"place":"',
                    field->>'place',
                    ',NYC"}'
                  )::json
where id =1;

update test
set field = '{"place":"SFO"}'::json
where id =2;
```